# semimartingale bound

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the d-dim. semimartingale $X_t=\int_0^t b_s\,ds+\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dW_s$ on a finite time horizon $[0,T]$ w.r.t. the Filtration $F_t$, where $W$ is a d-dim. Brownian Motion. We assume that $b$ and $\sigma$ are continuous and adapted. Furthermore let $\eta_t=\sup(||b_u-b_0||^2:u\in[0,t])$, wherer $||\cdot||$ is the d-dim. Euclidean norm. Then the claim is $\||E(X_t|F_0)-tb_0||\leq t\eta_t$.

We can write $X_t=\int_0^t (b_s-b_0)\,ds+tb_0+\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dW_s$. Noting that $\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dW_s$ is a martingal starting at $0$ and using the fact that $b_0$ is $F_0$-measurable by assumption, we have

$||E(X_t|F_0)-tb_0||=||E(\int_0^t (b_s-b_0)\,ds+tb_0|F_0)-tb_0||=||E(\int_0^t (b_s-b_0)\,ds|F_0)||$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that the upper bound is $t \eta_t$ and not $t \mathbb{E}(\eta_t \mid \mathcal{F}_0)$...?

Comment: Based on scaling considerations, and the exponent 2 in the definition of $\eta_t$, the correct bound ought to be $t\Bbb E(\sqrt{\eta_t}\mid \mathcal F_0)$.

Comment: I was also sceptical, that is why I asked. I'm pretty sure I gave the right scenario. It is derived in the proof of Lemma 4.1 in a paper by Jacod and Rosenbaum in 2013 called "quarticity and other functions of volatility". In that paper a function $b'$ is used, but it should also work for such $b$ as above, because it is a special case.